# AngularJS ng-hide ng-show or ng-if based on active state of array items

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

hi so i am building a shopping cart and it has 3 views menu,options,and order. The list is built using ng-repeat from json data. each item in the array as an active field set to false. when an item is added to the order its value is set to true. what i would like to do is when no products in the array are active i would like to hide the option markup and show a "please add items markup" same with the order page.. but my questions is how do i go about and check the entire array and using that boolean to display the view or the "add items markup"

here is my factory function

```
OrderFactory.checkActive = function(item){

    angular.forEach(item, function(item){
        if (item.active){
            $scope.show = false;
        } else {
            $scope.show = true;
        }
    });

}
```

here is what i'm trying to show/hide

```
<md-card ng-show="!show">
<md-card-content>
  <h1>Please add items</h1>
</md-card-content>
<md-card>

<md-card ng-show="show">
<md-card-content>
    <h3 class="md-subhead" align="center">Review And Submit Order</h3>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-list ng-repeat="item in menu | filter:true">
        <md-list-item layout="row">
            <h3>{{ item.name }} Qty:{{item.qty}}</h3>
            <span flex></span>
            <h3>{{ item.price | currency }}</h3>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="size in item.sizes | filter:true">
            <span>{{ size.name }}</span>
            <span flex></span>
            <span>{{ size.price | currency }}</span>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="flavor in item.flavors | filter:true">
            <span>{{ flavor.name }}</span>
            <span flex></span>
            <span>{{ flavor.price | currency }}</span>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-list>
        <md-list-item layout="row">
            <h3 class="md-subhead">Order Total:</h3>
            <span flex></span>
            <h3>{{ total(menu) | currency }}</h3>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

any ideas? thanks for looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer to do it on HTML itself using filter.

Your`ng-if`/`ng-show` condition would be `ng-if="(menu | filter : {active: true}).length == 0"`

**Markup**

```
<md-card ng-if="(menu | filter : {active: true}).length == 0">
<md-card-content>
  <h1>Please add items</h1>
</md-card-content>
<md-card>

<md-card ng-if="(menu | filter : {active: true}).length > 0">
<md-card-content>
   ..content here
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: I choose this answer but both answers are correctly working.. thank you

Comment: It's great that there were two solutions for this same problem.  I do personally like this solution since it move the logic into the very spot it's being used right now.  Less clutter this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your foreach code keeps overwriting the value stored in `$scope.show`.  It will only remember the final iteration.  Since your are looking for if there are *any* active items, you should return as soon as you find an active item.

Using your foreach:

```
OrderFactory.checkActive = function(item){
    $scope.show = true; //default to true
    angular.forEach(item, function(item){
        if (item.active){  //only change value if found an active item
            $scope.show = false;
            break;
        } 
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Array.some(predicate)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if there are any active items.

```
$scope.show = !itemArray.some(function(item) {
    return item.active;
});
```

Comment: oh i see... both answer are working good but i do like the html version a little better... thanks for a great answer

Comment: Yep it's definitely more elegant.  Glad to help.

Comment: @ryanyuyu you catch was also nice..Specifically like that ` Array.some(predicate)` part..Its awesome..+1